# No column name was specified for column 2 of 'a' error

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have a MySQL query and I ran it working fine but same query showing error in SQL Server.

SQL Server query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) cnt 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         tc_id, MAX(exn_time), STATUS 
     FROM 
         release_details a, tc_details b  
     WHERE 
         a.project = b.project 
         AND a.tc_id = b.tc_name 
         AND logicaldel = 0 
         AND a.project = 'test' 
     GROUP BY 
         tc_id, STATUS) a 
WHERE 
    a.status = 'PASS';
```

Error:

> No column name was specified for column 2 of 'a'.

How do I modify the above query?

Comment: MAX(exn_time) GiveMeAColumnName

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style should **no longer be used** and instead it is recommended to use the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax introduced with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Also: if you use *table aliases*, then please try to use a **more meaningful** alias rather than just `a`, `b` ....... `rd` for `release_details` and `tc` for `tc_details` would be just ***so much more intuitive*** than `a`, `b` .....

Answer (score 7):

Use the `Alias name` for your inner query.You are getting the `MAX(exn_time)` but not specified the name for that column that's why throwing the error. And you can use the `Joins` to the tables to make it more readable.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt 
FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT 
         tc_id,
         MAX(exn_time) AS Maxtime ,
         STATUS 
      FROM 
         release_details a JOIN tc_details b  
           ON a.project= b.project 
             AND a.tc_id = b.tc_name 
      WHERE 
           logicaldel = 0  
           AND a.project ='test' 
      GROUP BY 
         tc_id,
         STATUS 
      ) a 
 WHERE a.status='PASS';
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to give `Alias name` inside subquery

Also as mentioned by Marc_s you need to use proper `Inner Join`, keep the join condition `ON` clause and move the filter to `where` clause

```
SELECT Count(*) cnt
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT tc_id,
                        Max(exn_time) Max_exn_time,
                        STATUS
        FROM   release_details a
               INNER JOIN tc_details b
                       ON a.project = b.project
                          AND a.tc_id = b.tc_name
        WHERE  a.project = 'test'
               AND logicaldel = 0
        GROUP  BY tc_id,
                  STATUS) a
WHERE  a.status = 'PASS';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is obviously that your second column in the resultset a doesn't have an alias.
You can rewrite the whole query to this for the same result:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT tc_id) cnt
FROM 
    release_details a
JOIN
    tc_details b  
ON
    a.project = b.project 
    AND a.tc_id = b.tc_name 
WHERE
    logicaldel = 0 
    AND a.project = 'test' 
    AND STATUS = 'PASS'
```

Since STATUS only can have the value 'PASS', MAX(exn_time) is not helping your counting, DISTINCT should not be used in the beginning of a SELECT when using group by like in your case, it is redundant